Chrome permission for clipboard-write returns 'granted' but prompts user
I'm using the following code to check if the the navigator has permission to write to the clipboard:
window.onload = () => {
  navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-write' }).then((permission) => {
    console.log(permission.state);
    if (permission.state === 'granted') {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText('sample text');
    }
  });
}

In Chrome, it returns "granted", however I get a prompt "See text and images copied to the clipboard" with the option to "Allow" or "Block". Shouldn't it return "prompt" instead?

I’ve experienced the same issue a long time ago. I think this behavior comes from browsers trying to protect user privacy and security. Hence, even thought clipboard access is granted, specific actions may not be allowed.
Hence, to know if copying text to the clipboard is allowed, you can await the result of the Promise returned by writeText.
navigator.clipboard.writeText(“some data”)
    .then(/** copied */)
    .catch(/** permission error/user rejection */);

Coupled with your code, this could allow you to perform the permission check you want to do.

That is what I ended up doing, but I was curious about this behaviour cause it seems incorrect. Thanks.
